# How to use while loops properly?

Tags: c++

I'm a beginner in programming and here you could see that this program will get ask the user to input their grade from their first to third periodic, which will then display the average. Everything was going fine not until I get to the part where the user will be asked if he would like to average another set, when I type y(yes) it'll loop the whole thing again and again starting from the *"your average grade is.."*. To me, I think the problem was about my bad looping. Why did that loop only that line and not the whole program? Any way I could improve my looping and programming? Is there anyway I could shorten this program?

Thanks for the time you gave answering this question.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using std::cout, std::cin, std::string,std::endl;
int main() {
  char again{};
  double P1{}, P2{}, P3{}, Grade{}, Result{};
string phrase  {"Your average grade is "},
       phrase1 {"Error! number should be in range of (1 to 100)."},
       result1 {"Failed"},
       result2 {"Study Harder"}, 
       result3 {"Job well done"}, 
       result4 {"Very good student"}, 
       result5 {"Exceptional student"};

cout<<"Enter your P1 grade: ";
cin>> P1;
cout<<"Enter your P2 grade: ";
cin>> P2;
cout<<"Enter your P3 grade: ";
cin>> P3; 
cout<<"\n";
while(P1 > 100 || P1 <= 0){
  cout << phrase1  << endl;
       cout << "Enter the Your P1 grade again: ";
          cin>> P1;}
while(P2 > 100 || P2 <= 0){ 
   cout << phrase1  << endl;
       cout << "Enter the Your P2 grade again: ";
          cin>> P2;}
 while(P3 > 100 || P3 <= 0){ 
   cout << phrase1  << endl;
       cout << "Enter the Your P3 grade again: ";
          cin>> P3;
          cout<<"\n";}
do{
Result = P1 * 0.33 + P2 *0.33 + P3 *0.34;
if (Result <= 49)
  cout<< phrase << Result << ", " << result1<<endl;
if (Result >= 50 && Result <= 70)
  cout<< phrase << Result << ", " << result2<<endl;
if (Result >= 71 && Result <= 80)
  cout<< phrase << Result << ", " << result3<<endl;
if (Result >= 81 && Result <= 90)
  cout<< phrase << Result << ", " << result4<<endl;
if (Result >= 91 && Result <= 100)
  cout<< phrase << Result << ", " << result5<<endl;
 cout<<"Would you like to average another set?(Y/N) ";
 cin>>again;
 cout<<"\n";
}while(toupper(again) =='Y' );//asks if the user would like to do another set 
return 0;
}
```

[image: The Error]

Comment: Where, in your `do{...}while(toupper(again)=='Y')` loop, do you ask users to input new values for `P1`, `P2`, or `P3`?

Comment: Yes, I wanted to do whole another set. But the problem is this code keeps looping
`do{...}while(toupper(again)=='Y')`

Comment: Right. Let's say someone enters `Y` and you go back to the top of your `do` loop. You don't ask for new values for `P1`, `P2`, and `P3`. So it will compute the exact same sum it computed last time, display the same phrase, and prompt you if you'd like to retry. If you want to get different values, you need to ask for them. Perhaps consider writing a function that reads in the values and returns the sum?

Comment: You might want to learn to use a debugger so you can step through your code line-by-line. That will let you see which lines prompt for and read grades and which lines are inside your loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your while loop is triggered, it goes back to `do` statement and executes the program from there.

Now the problem is that the value in the `do` scope doesn't get updated because you are not giving input again.

The simple solution I believe is that you should move your `do` statement to the top.

```cpp
do {
    cout << "Enter your P1 grade: ";
    // rest of the code here...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm laughing so hard how stupid I am right now, that problem so hard could be solved by putting the `do{` at the beginning of the input of the program. But why did loop in _do_ instead of the while loop?

Comment: Sorry, I don't get what u mean by "But why did loop in do instead of the while loop"

Comment: Because the `do..while` loop loops the stuff after the `do` and before the `while` and not the stuff outside the block. You have four separate loops in your code, three `while` loops and one `do..while` loop. They each occur in sequence and there's never a point where the `do..while` loop will go back up to the beginning of a prior `while` loop.

Comment: if u want to loop without the usage of do just remove do and at the position of do put `while(again=='y'){code here}` and before while loop set again='y'